# Resolving Avro schema order when generating sources using avro-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, avro, avro-tools

We're using `avro-maven-plugin` to generate java classes for our Avro schemas, the schemas nest each other to reuse common elements, all fairly vanilla. The piece I can't figure out is how to elegantly make the pom file for this.

To get the schemas to resolve for the nesting we have to use `<Include>` lines to load the schema in the correct order, otherwise the class files won't generate. The plugin section ends up looking like below, but with about 50 lines of `<Include></Include>` because the schema is quite large.

I've been googling around but I feel like I must be overlooking or misunderstanding something, Avro's been around for a long time, nested schemas have been around for a long time, this plugin has been around for a long time, what am I missing to have it auto-resolve the dependencies to avoid 50 lines of `<Include>` carefully crafted in the correct order? All I'm finding is a handful of references to doing exactly this, `<Include>` lines. Is there a better way? Thanks.

```
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>avro-schema-code-generation</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.avro</include>
                            </includes>
                            <imports>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/com/ourapp/common/shared1.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/com/ourapp/common/shared2.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/com/ourapp/common/shared3.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/com/ourapp/common/shared4.avsc</import>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/com/ourapp/common/shared5.avsc</import>

                            </imports>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/avro/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin --> I don't know of a better way with Maven, but if you're willing to switch to Gradle, this plugin resolves schema imports automatically, no need to specify them at all.